# Copy valuem to EmptyRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have this code:

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("WREQ");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Orders/Deliveries");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange("A2:X");;

  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,  3,  1,  1);
    // copy values to destination range
     source.copyTo(destination);
     copySheet.deleteRows(2, source.getNumRows())
    
}
```

it copies the information in A2:X from `WREQ` sheet and paste it at the last row +1 of `Orders/Deliveries` sheet starting from column c. The problem is that on the `pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,  3,  1,  1);`  it literally grab the last empty row, and as I have formulas and check boxes on the Orders/Deliveries A,B columns (for control) it makes the script to understand that the row is not empty and go for the next one, generally going way down.

I want it to ignore the A,B columns as they are control columns and check if the last row starting from column C, if C is empty than paste the data and carry on with the rest of the script.

Not sure how to include on this code tho, as I'm very lame on coding. i was considering the isBlank, but not sure how to make it work the way i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If there are no gaps in the data (column C) you can try

```js
var lastRow = pasteSheet.getRange("C:C").getValues().filter(String).length;
```

Then use this variable in the next line

```
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,  3,  1,  1);
```

- If there are gaps (empty cells) in the data range, you can create a helper function to compute the first free row in a column (2nd parameter passed to the function).

```js
function findFirstFreeRow(sheet, colNum) {
    var v = sheet.getRange(1, colNum, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(),
        l = v.length,
        r;
    while (l > 0) {
        if (v[l] && v[l][0].toString().length > 0) {
            r = (l + 2);
            break;
        } else {
            l--;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Then call this function to obtain the first free row

```
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(findFirstFreeRow(pasteSheet, 3), 3,  1,  1);
```

Comment: Fantastic, the second option work perfectly. So grateful for all your assistance, thank you a lot for that!

Comment: Most welcome, @RafaNHS. Glad to hear I was able to help.